# JS Нужно получить текст тэга h1 со страницы другого сайта?

Tags: javascript, html

Есть группа сайтов. Адреса их известны.
У каждого из них заголовок на главной прописан в тэг h1.
Нужно сделать скрипт, который обойдет их все и соберет в массив все тексты из этих тегов.
Я попробовал (пока без обхода) так:

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$.get('http://siteadress.ru', null, function(txt){
    alert($(txt).text($("h1").text()));
});
</script>
```

Но оно, естественно, не прошло, т.к. $.get лишь получает текст документа, а не генерирует сайт. А сайт - на php, на drupal, поэтому в тексте index.php нет h1.

Что подскажет совет мудрейших?

Comment: Чет вы батенька какую-то хрень затеяли, сайты на клиентском js парсить. Да и cors таки, вам их просто так не отдадут, если они не ваши конечно.

Comment: Тогда подскажите мне как быть.
Нужно с 50+ сайтов собрать:  
1) Местоположение (вытащить из вызова Яндекс-карты)  
2) Название организации (h1)  
...и создать из этого сводную карту подразделений.

Comment: Парсить сайты на серверсайде. Выдавать с серверсайда апишку, которую ваш клиент будет дергать.

Comment: Есть некоторое базовое ограничение безопасности веб, называемое same origin policy. Значительной частью зашитое на уровне браузеров. Если вкратце, то вашему клиенту с одного сайта, другой сайт просто так ничего не отдаст. Есть множество нюансов, но в целом это так. Откройте консольку на этом сайте и попробуйте отправьте гет запрос на ваш сайт из примера, и увидите что что-то пошло не так.

Comment: Сейчас вынесу в ответ пожалуй.

Comment: А как вообще подобные вопросы решают?
Вот, есть список подразделений. А нужно их все на карту нанести. Вручную что-ли? Или базу одну на всех? Ну, нехорошо же двойную работу делать...

Comment: Нужно смотреть нюансы. Все сайты ваши? Тогда можно сделать апишку, которая информацию нужную вам будет сразу отдавать, а не парсить свои же клиенты. Ну то есть вы как-то плохо понимаете клиент-сервер концепцию. Зачем перекладывать на клиент странную работу?

Comment: Сайты - мои.
Кстати, все Яндекс-карты с расположением подразделений - тоже я делал. Они с одного аккаунта Яндекс созданы. Но Яндексы сказали, что сделать сводную карту из разных карт одного аккаунта пока нельзя.

Comment: Так, по ходу мы переходим от технической задачи указанной в вопросе к значительно более широкой "фиче-бизнесовой", с которой я разбираться не готов.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В общем случае средствами лишь браузерного js так сделать **нельзя**.

**Почему:** [Same origin policy.](https://learn.javascript.ru/same-origin-policy)

Это базовый принцип безопасности веб. У него есть множество нюансов, но в целом оно говорит что клиенту одного сайта другой сайт просто так по http запросу никто ничего не отдаст.

Можно открыть консоль браузера на этом сайте, ручками отправить запрос на сайт из вопроса и убедиться что что-то пошло не так.

**Что делать:**
Если все сайты - ваши, то можно разрешить на них кросдоменные запросы, но в таком случае вам не нужны эти странные операции, зачем парсить свои же сайты, когда можно получить информацию из более надежных источников.

В общем случае это делается на серверсаде. Кросдоменные ограничения реализуются в основном на уровне браузера, то есть сервер может собирать и парсить сайты, выставлять на клиент некое API, которое клиент просто будет вызывать и получать нужную информацию.

Comment: Также оно обходится добавлением https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/ перед http://siteadress.ru, чтобы получилось https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/http://siteadress.ru - этакий хороший сервис :)

Comment: @TimurMusharapov, ага спасибо, про сервис не знал) Но по моему в любом случае логичнее запилить свою серверную прослойку.